# Are questions about hardware development on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Right now the [on-topic FAQ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) reads:

> Please refrain from asking about the following topics:
>
> Code-level programming questions (cocoa, LLVM, etc…) are off-topic here. We do encourage AppleScript, Automator, and UNIX shell scripting questions as well as how to use tools like Xcode for non-language specific tasks.

But today I noticed this question that is seemingly about hardware development; the asker expresses their desire to "build a device".

[Homekit: multi mode button in home app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/389433/18101)

Our FAQ doesn't call out hardware development as being off-topic. Should it? And do we care about whether development is for distribution or just for private use as hobbyists?

Comment: This is such an edge case; coming up with a policy to address wouldn’t be effective or efficient.

Comment: Software development is well covered by another site hardware not so much.